# My array is only printing 0s--java

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program in java about having to extract the multiples of four from a program. The program looks like this:

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class Assignment8
    {
        public static void main ( String [] args )
        {
            int i = 0;
            int [] array1 = new int[100];  // creating an array of 100 numbers

            for (int number = 1; number < 100; number++)
            {
                array1[number] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);    
            }

            System.out.println("The numbers divisible by four are: " + Arrays.toString(Isdivisibleby4( array1 )));
        }

         public static int [] Isdivisibleby4(int [] v)
{

    int arraysize = 0;         
    for( int i = 0; i < v.length; i++ )
        if( v[i] % 4 == 0 )
                arraysize++;

    int [] divisibilityArray = new int[arraysize];  

    int j = 0;         

    for( int i = 0; i < v.length; i++ )
    {
            if( i % 4 == 0)
            {
                j++;
            }
    }
    return divisibilityArray;
}
```

}

However, the output is only 0s.
Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never copied any numbers into `divisibilityArray`.  You probably want to add something like

```
divisibilityArray[j] = v[i];
```

inside the `if` condition, above `j++;`.  This will make sure an entry actually gets copied from one array to the other.

Also, the `if` condition should probably be `if( v[i] % 4 == 0 )`, instead of `if( i % 4 == 0 )`.  Otherwise, you'll get every fourth number, instead of every multiple of 4; and you may even get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.